# Python Bell sound for windows or Mac without terminal

Tags: python, audio, terminal, stdout

I have a program that I would like to use the internal bell sound "\a" for since it works both on linux, windows, and macs without an additional files. Works great when the program runs as .py,  However, I also want my program to run without an open terminal window, so it does not work when the program runs as .pyw , since the program is not connected to stdout.

Right now I use sys.stdout.write('\a') to sound the alarm, but without the program attached to a terminal, the sound does not fire (and eventually leads to the crash of the program).

again, I'd like to do something that is default to all terminal systems, so i'm trying to avoid including a sound file and playing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a [forum post](https://lists.gt.net/python/dev/699417#p699204) saying that the following code snippet would work:

```
import Tkinter
Tkinter.Tk().bell()
```

I'm not quiet sure if it's working. I'm on a Linux and I couldn't make your command running on my machine (maybe it's disabled by the administrator or something else).

Note that the snippet above opens a Tkinter window. I think it won't be a big problem to hide the window and close it after the beep is played (wait for a second or bell() has a kind of event listener).

Sorry for not enough going into detail. I'm just hoping that I can give you a hint because I can't test it on my own. Good luck! :)

Comment: Great, i'm already using Tkinter for the application.  Tried it without a terminal and it worked the first time.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming platform.system () gives you the name of the OS, you could use the follwing on Linux and Windows. It gives you some freedom to choose a particular sound.

```
if platform.system () == 'Linux':
    import pyaudio
else:
    import winsound

class BeepBase:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.normalPars = (1000, 0.1)
        self.specialPars = (2100, 0.1)
        self.attentionPars = (400, 0.5)

if platform.system () == 'Linux':
    class Beep (BeepBase):
        def __init__ (self):
            BeepBase.__init__ (self)

            self.sampleFreq = 16000
            self.sampleTime = 1. / self.sampleFreq
            self.attackTime = 0.001
            self.decayTime = 0.015

            self.normalWave = self.getWave (*self.normalPars)
            self.specialWave = self.getWave (*self.specialPars) 
            self.attentionWave = self.getWave (*self.attentionPars)

            # self.pyAudio = pyaudio.PyAudio () # Gives errors

        def done (self):    # Never called, may leak resources
            self.pyAudio.terminate ()

        def getWave (self, frequency, duration):
            wave = ''.join ([
                chr (int (128 + 127 * math.sin (2 * math.pi * frequency * time) * max (0, min (1, min (time/self.attackTime, (duration - time)/self.decayTime)))))
                for time in [self.sampleTime * iSample for iSample in xrange (int (duration / self.sampleTime))]
            ])

            return wave

        def any (self, wave):
            self.stream = self.pyAudio.open (
                format = self.pyAudio.get_format_from_width (1),
                channels = 1,
                rate = self.sampleFreq,
                output = True
            )
            sleep (0.025)
            self.stream.write (wave)
            sleep (0.15)
            self.stream.stop_stream ()
            self.stream.close ()

        def normal (self):
            if main.settings.sound:
                self.any (self.normalWave)

        def special (self):
            if main.settings.sound:
                self.any (self.specialWave)

        def attention (self):
            if main.settings.sound:
                self.any (self.attentionWave)
else:
    class Beep (BeepBase):
        def normal (self):
            if main.settings.sound:
                winsound.Beep (self.normalPars [0], int (self.normalPars [1] * 1000))

        def special (self):
            if main.settings.sound:
                winsound.Beep (self.specialPars [0], int (self.specialPars [1] * 1000))     

        def attention (self):
            if main.settings.sound:
                winsound.Beep (self.attentionPars [0], int (self.attentionPars [1] * 1000))

beep = Beep ()
```